# Local Notification in ionic framework

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, localnotification

I am developing an android music app in ionic framework like `gaana.com` or `saavn`.

If any song is playing then one notification should appear (shown in image) with `image, buttons or song details`. So my problem is, I don't have any idea how to bring it.

- Shall I need to use [Cordova local Notification plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/)? If I use this then how could I add buttons and button events? And one large image? I followed their docs but I didn't get anything to add buttons. (Or am I missing something?)
- If `cordova local notification` is not the solution the what should I use?
- I want to add this feature like: `user can't close the notification. If song get stopped then only notification gets automatically closed.` is that possible ?

May be the question is very very silly.. But I stucked.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you should use this notification plugin and no, you can't include play buttons.

Comment: @Joerg is there any other way to achieve the requirement?

Comment: And one more thing @Joerg .. I want to add this feature like: `user can't close the notification. If song get stopped then only notification gets automatically closed.` . Is that possible ?

Comment: First question: I think you have to modify the plugin or wright your own. Second question: AFAIK yes, the property is called ongoing, see here: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling

Comment: Thanks @Joerg for the info